# PHP's preg_match() and preg_match_all() functions

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

What do the [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) functions do and how can I use them?

Comment: I assume that you've looked at the PHP documentation already? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: @Philip: yes, I did but I didn`t understand it.

Comment: The documentation did not explain differences between this 2. It took a little while to read but answer given from people here saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`preg_match` stops looking after the first match. `preg_match_all`, on the other hand, continues to look until it finishes processing the entire string. Once match is found, it uses the remainder of the string to try and apply another match.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Thanks, this answer is much more useful to me than the chosen one, because you actually simplify how the docs explain it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 20):

Both [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) functions in PHP use Perl compatible regular expressions.

You can watch this series to fully understand Perl compatible regular expressions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVZOJ1rEnUg&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGRPyPMGuLPWuiWgEI9Kp1w

### preg_match($pattern, $subject, &$matches, $flags, $offset)

The `preg_match` function is used to search for a particular `$pattern` in a `$subject` string and when the pattern is found the first time, it stops searching for it. It outputs matches in the `$matches`, where `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized sub-pattern, and so on.

#### Example of `preg_match()`

```php
<?php
preg_match(
    "|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",
    "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>",
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "<b>example: </b>"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "example: "
}
```

### preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, &$matches, $flags)

The `preg_match_all` function searches for all the matches in a string and outputs them in a multi-dimensional array (`$matches`) ordered according to `$flags`. When no `$flags` value is passed, it orders results so that `$matches[0]` is an array of full pattern matches, `$matches[1]` is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized sub-pattern, and so on.

#### Example of `preg_match_all()`

```php
<?php
preg_match_all(
    "|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",
    "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>",
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "<b>example: </b>"
    [1]=>
    string(36) "<div align=left>this is a test</div>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "example: "
    [1]=>
    string(14) "this is a test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A concrete example:

```
preg_match("/find[ ]*(me)/", "find me find   me", $matches):
$matches = Array(
    [0] => find me
    [1] => me
)

preg_match_all("/find[ ]*(me)/", "find me find   me", $matches):
$matches = Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => find me
            [1] => find   me
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => me
            [1] => me
        )
)

preg_grep("/find[ ]*(me)/", ["find me find    me", "find  me findme"]):
$matches = Array
(
    [0] => find me find    me
    [1] => find  me findme
)
```