# How to find all matching patterns in a string using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string that looks like this

```
Hello, my name is "{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ) }}" and my title is "{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 title FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ) }}"
```

I need to be able to take this string and parse out any pattern that matches the following pattern `{{ @sql(WHATEVER QUERY GOES HERE) }}` it must start with two braken followed by optional spaces and then `@sql(` ending in `) }}`

Additionally, I will also need to extract the inner query which is the text that is found between `@sql(` and ending in `) }}`
Here is what I have done

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s*+@sql\((.+)\)+\s*+\}\}/i';

$matches = [];

preg_match    ( $pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

My pattern works for the following string

```
Hello "{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ) }}"
```

but when I need to use the pattern more than once in the text, it seems that my pattern search for the last occurrence of `)}}` instead of the next occurrence.

How can I update my pattern so it looks for one ore multiple matches?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match and preg\_match\_all functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088836/php-preg-match-and-preg-match-all-functions)

Comment: Have you noticed that _None_ of your sample strings like this `"{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 }}"` will match with a regex template like `{{ @sql(WHATEVER QUERY GOES HERE) }}` ?

Comment: Why are you using possessive quantifiers `*+` ?

Comment: You have to use a regex tailored to parsing sql, otherwise you can't interpret what's between `@sql(here)`

Comment: @sln thanks for the correction. I just updated my question again to add the `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, I guess you need `preg_replace()`:

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello, my name is "{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ) }}" and my title is "{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 title FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ) }}"';

$regex = '~
            \{{2}\h*@sql\(    # start of outer part
            (?P<query>[^()]+) # inner query
            \)\h*\}{2}        # end of outer part
        ~x';

$string = preg_replace($regex, '$1', $string);
echo $string;
# Hello, my name is "SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 " and my title is "SELECT TOP 1 title FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 "

?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/1qkuaf).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I need the inner query. I am kinds confused on how to loop over the results. also, the inner query is giving me an additional `)` at the end

Comment: Actually, all I am interested in is the inner query, I don't care about the rest. If it is easier just to get an array with only the inner queries that would be perfect

Comment: That makes more sense now. But the query is still returning an extra `)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you Jan. This caused another issue in index 0 which is the exact string that is found. it is missing the ending `) }}` so the query is being returned correctly but the string that is found it returnes `{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ` instead of `{{ @sql(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table1 WHERE [id] = 5 ) }}` I need the whole thing so I can replace the whole string found with the result of the query

Comment: I want to replace the string starting at `{{ @Sql(.....) }} `with the result of the inner query. I got the query and executed it with no issue. but in order to replace `{{ @Sql(.....) }}` with the query result, I need to know the whole `{{ @Sql(.....) }}`  if you look at the demo you posted you will see how the ending `) }}` is removed but I need to keep it in order to replace the string correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114566/discussion-between-jaylen-and-jan).

Answer (score 0):

You should just make the regex non-gready, by adding `?`

```
...(.+?)...
```

(And also use `preg_match_all`)

Comment: Thank you for that. One thing I forgot to mention in my question "I will edit it next" is that the second index of the pattern is to extract query which is find inside the `@sql(QUERY)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I do it is this: You don't want any other braces within one pair of opening and closing braces. So you can specify this:

```
[^\{\}]+
```

The above pattern will match any string of characters that does not contain a curly bracket. Your complete pattern would be

```
/\{\{ ?@sql\([^\{\}]+\) ?\}\}/i
```

Comment: This return the entire text starting with {{ and ending with }}. All I need to return is the query that is between `{{ @sql(` and `) }}`