# Perl to PHP equivalent: extract strings with regex

Tags: php, regex, perl

What is the PHP equivalent for this Perl code?

```
my $html = '<tr class="aaa"><td class="bbb">111.111.111.111</td><td>443</td><td><div><span class="ccc"></span> example <span> example</span></div></td></tr><tr class="aaa"><td class="bbb">222.222.222.222</td><td>443</td><td><div><span class="ccc"></span> example <span> example</span></div></td></tr>';

print "$1:$2\n" while $html =~ /class="aaa"><td class="bbb">(.*?)<\/td><td>(\d+)<\/td>/g;
```

I tried with this code, but it gives infinite loop.

```
while(preg_match('/td class=\"bbb\">(.*?)<\/td><td>(\d+)<\/td>/',$html,$out)) {
        echo "$out[1]:$out[2]\n";
    }
```

Also, with `if` instead of `while` it gives only one result.

Expected output (IP:PORT):

```
111.111.111.111:443
222.222.222.222:443
```

Environment: **Windows 7** with **PHP 5.5.12** (WAMP v2.5).

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this going? That might help us understand the problems you're facing :)

Comment: I tried with this code, but it gives infinite loop: `while(preg_match('/td class=\"bbb\">(.*?)<\/td><td>(\d+)<\/td>/',$html,$out)) {
  echo "$out[1]:$out[2]\n";
 }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the PHP code there. It's hard to read in the comment.

Comment: Also, with **if** insted of **while** it gives only one result.

Comment: You should look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088836/php-preg-match-and-preg-match-all-functions) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19767391/2233391) given, I think that will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Henders that explains the difference, but not what OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @simbabque agreed, but it does point them in the right direction based on their comment _'with if insted of while it gives only one result'_. Looks like they were on the right track initially and then diverted when only a single result was returned.

Comment: @Henders I agree. But there is more, because `preg_match_all` also seems to only return _if_ it matched. Coming from a Perl background, I would iterate the matches array [as shown in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38586866/1331451). That might not be the most  efficient way, and simply saying `if(preg_match_all(...))` and then using `$matches` might suffice, but I don't have a PHP to test it.

Comment: @simbabque I've just tested it and on PHP 5.5.9 you can do that no problem. As you suggested, `if(preg_match_all(...))` and then `print_r($matches)` gives you the array of matches.

Comment: You should add that as an answer @Henders. Mine explains the _why_ part, but my lack of PHP knowledge is clearly visible. ;)

Comment: Can you provide an example of your expected output, please? When I [run your code on PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/in7p-rb4g) it gives me a result that doesn't look like what you are looking for...

Comment: @Henders: If there are no matches then the `$out` array will be empty, so simply printing its contents regardless of the return value of `preg_match_all` will do the right thing.

Comment: @Borodin I was missing the `PREG_SET_ORDER`. Nice spot!

Comment: @Henders: That just reorders the contents of `$out`; all of the information is there with or without it.

Comment: @Borodin Much more easy to access the data though! :) I'll remember that flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do as you ask. It uses `preg_match_all` as [simbabque described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38586866/622310)

```php
<?php

$html = '<tr class="aaa"><td class="bbb">221.86.2.163</td><td>443</td><td><div><span class="ccc"></span> example <span> example</span></div></td></tr><tr class="aaa"><td class="bbb">221.86.2.163</td><td>443</td><td><div><span class="ccc"></span> example <span> example</span></div></td></tr>';

preg_match_all('|td class="bbb">([\d.]+)</td><td>(\d+)</td>|', $html, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ( $out as $item ) {
    echo "$item[1]:$item[2]\n";
}

?>
```

### output

```
221.86.2.163:443
221.86.2.163:443
```

Comment: That's it, this solved my problem. PREG_SET_ORDER is the man, without it doesn't work! :D

Thank you.

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php): _"PREG_SET_ORDER - Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of first set of matches, $matches[1] is an array of second set of matches, and so on."_

Comment: At first, I tried with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, I scraped the IPs, but I couldn't ports.

Comment: *"without [PREG_SET_ORDER] it doesn't work"* Yes, it does work without that flag. It's simpler to unpack the contents of `$out` if you use it, but all the information is in there either way.

Comment: @Borodin So, how to access the information without setting PREG_SET_ORDER flag? What is that "unpack" thing, how it works, how to do that?

Is there any other way to do it without storing the information into the `$out` array? Something simple as the Perl code provided in the main question, something like `if you find a match - print it, if you find a match - print it, if you find a match - print it` etc.

Comment: @Henders Thank you, I'm new here, I didn't know about 'accepted answer'.

Comment: @tr0in: If you have something else to ask then you should open a new question.

Comment: Haha, I should wait 5 days because I have reached the question limit, stackoverflow says. It's because someone downvote my question.

Comment: @tr0in: It's becaused *six people* downvoted your question, and rightly so. You can't just post your work on Stack Overflow and wait for someone else to do it. You should spend those days reading through [***How do I ask a good question?***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `preg_match()` [returns an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) that indicates if it matched. You are only looking at that return value in your loop, so that condition will always be true. That's why you have an infinite loop.

Since `preg_match`'s `$matches` only gives you all capture groups from matching once, you only get the first match when used with an `if`.

The Perl code has the `/g` modifier on the regular expression match, which makes the match *global*. The match operator `=~` returns a true value for each match. It's basically an iterator, so the `while` loop will go through all matches without repeating a match, so there is no infinite lop. Then the match variables `$1` and `$2` are used to display results. You need to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get a global match in PHP.

You need to first match, then iterate the array with the matches. Since the first element is the full match, you can ignore that.

```
preg_match_all('/td class=\"bbb\">(.*?)<\/td><td>(\d+)<\/td>/',$html,$out);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($out) - 1; $i += 2) {
    echo "$out[$i]:";
    echo $out[$i+1];
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Nope. I changed echo `"$out\n";` to `echo "$match\n";` but `preg_match` gives only the first match with newline between IP and Port. `preg_match_all` gives error **Notice: Array to string conversation bla bla bla**.

Comment: @tr0in see my update. I need to read phpdoc for syntax because I am not usually using php. The foreach approach was wrong, I didn't see that there are two matches in the regex at first.

Comment: That regex is better as, for instance, `'td class="bbb">(.*?)</td><td>(\d+)</td>'`

Comment: Which regex @Borodin?

Comment: @simbabque I see your update, but its same. It gives error: **Notice: Array to string conversation bla bla bla.** for 3rd and 4th line from your code - `$out[$i]` and `$out[$i+1]`.

Comment: As I said, I'm not a PHP guy. Treat this as pseudo-code and work with it. @Henders [gives good advice in their comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586517/perl-to-php-equivalent-extract-strings-with-regex?noredirect=1#comment64562734_38586517) on the question. I believe that approach is easier, though you still might need a loop if you don't know how many matches you will have.

Comment: OK @simbabque, thanks anyway, I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @simbabque: The regex in your solution. Just like in Perl, it's best to use different delimiters if the pattern itself contains slashes, and double quotes don't need escaping anyway.

Comment: @borodin I just copied it from the question. You're right of course.