# php extract Emoji from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, telegram, emoji

I have a string contain emoji.
I want extract emoji's from that string,i'm using below code but it doesn't what i want.

```
$string = " hello world ";

preg_match('/([0-9#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}\x{00a9}\x{203C}\x{2047}\x{2048}\x{2049}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{2139}\x{2122}\x{3297}\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?/u', $string, $emojis);
```

**i want this:**

```
$emojis =  ["", ""];
```

**but return this:**

```
$emojis = [""]
```

and also if:

```
$string = "☝"
```

it return only first emoji

```
$emoji = [""]
```

Comment: try `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try looking at `preg_match_all` function. `preg_match` stops looking after it finds the first match, which is why you're only ever getting the first emoji back.

Taken from [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19767391/1561469)

> `preg_match` stops looking after the first match. `preg_match_all`, on the other hand, continues to look until it finishes processing the entire string. Once match is found, it uses the remainder of the string to try and apply another match.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

So your code would become:

```
$string = " hello world ";

preg_match_all('/([0-9#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}\x{00a9}\x{203C}\x{2047}\x{2048}\x{2049}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{2139}\x{2122}\x{3297}\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?/u', $string, $emojis);

print_r($emojis[0]); // Array ( [0] =>  [1] =>  )
```

Comment: you can get the regular expression that supports new emojis from this [link](https://repl.it/@onlineth/PHP-Remove-Emojis)

Comment: Updated namal's link to include some Unicode 12.0 emojis including newest emoji, white heart. [link](https://repl.it/@Kornflake/PHP-Remove-Emojis#main.php)