# Wrap all emojis in a string with HTML?

Tags: php, regex

How would I take a text string with emojis and wrap each emoji in an HTML tag?

Example string...

```
str = "This is  a test with  emojis in the  string"
```

Desired output...

```
output = "This is <i></i> a test with <i></i> emojis in the <i></i> string"
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306245/php-extract-emoji-from-a-string, but it's not an answer to your exact question

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think with that question it can be extracted so easily it is a dup. https://3v4l.org/KZbbZ (unless there are emojis missing from that character list)

Comment: @user3783243 I would agree

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24840667/2191572 and https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex are probably the correct answer. Not quite sure that emoji regex needs a special post for PHP.

Answer (score -1):

This regex will match emojis:

```
[\{uD83C}-\x{DBFF}\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]+
```

Replace with:

```
<i>$0</i>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aGfJil/1/

Comment: This is too loose `µ` is not an emoji. https://regex101.com/r/aGfJil/2/