# not able to understand preg_match_all()

Tags: php

This question already has a duplicate question ([Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088836/php-preg-match-and-preg-match-all-functions))
I'm not able to create a comment there, so i'm creating a new one.

The solution provided is very explanatory, but I am still not able to get a clear view of `preg_match_all()` .

**I tried the following code**

```
preg_match_all("/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i","#test this is #php test",$matches);

var_dump($matches)
```

**The result is**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "#test"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "#php"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "test"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "php"
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the regex will only select the string starting with '#' as per my code.

But in the result, the array contains the string with '#' and without '#'.

Please help me figure this out. What am I missing.

Comment: `My understanding is that the regex will only select the starting with '#' as per my code` - thats because your understanding is wrong. You need to add the start of string `^` to the front of it.  `/^#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i`  The caret `^` when outside of a character group `[...]` means match the start of the `string/line`.  Inside the `[^0-9]` means `Not`, it's confusing.  But that is how it works. Also you can replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\w` which is the same thing.  And the `i` flag is pointless here, which  case insensitive, as you have both upper and lowercase. That gives us `/^#+(\w+)/`

Comment: In the first array there is result of the whole regexp. In the next array there are results of each bracket (in your case `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`).

Comment: Conversely the `$` matches the end.  I would have posted it as a answer, but I saw the duplicate link.  For the matches they are indexed by the capture groups `(...)` starting at `1`.  The `0` just like in `preg_match` is the "full match"

Comment: Take a look at the section on groups in the duplicate. Your `[0]` array elements match the entire regex i.e. `#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` => `['#test', '#php']`, the `[1]` elements match just the contents of the `()` i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` => `['test','php']`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix insight on `^` was a new information. thank you for that.

Comment: Sure, Regex can be very confusing. I am pretty good at it now after some years of struggling, although lookarounds still get me once in a while.  Regex is extremely powerful, so it's worth the work to learn it.  A good testing site is this, https://regex101.com/  Mainly because you can save your stuff, and it has built in documentation and a great regex parser.  it doesn't do everything correctly from a PHP standpoint, such as there is no `preg_match_all` but you can get close.

Comment: @Nick ok. but, in that case why did it skip the strings without # `this is`.

Comment: It skipped them due to the lack of both the `#` and a `\s` for spaces.  What your code does is match any part that starts with a `#` and is followed `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`.  No spaces.

Comment: @Braikedp because they do not match *the whole regex*.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Nick Thank you for the help. That is very informative and clarified my doubt.

Comment: Here is your Regex in the Testing site I mentioned above, https://regex101.com/r/5Sm864/1  if you look on the right it gives you a full explanation of what it does.  Which is why I like this tester so much.  Note the `g` flag is more of a Javascript Regex thing, then a PHP thing.  this is one of those things I said it's not 100% correct in PHP.