# Regex to get all href tags from text

Tags: php, regex

I have huge text which contains normal text and `href` tags. I want to retrieve all href tags by using regular expressions.

I tried `href="([^"]*)"` but it is returning only one `href` value.

```
 $result[] = $util->execute(self::$queryToGetContentFromPagesEng3); //getting text from database
 foreach ($result as $temp) {
   if(preg_match("href=\"([^\"]*)\"",$temp)) {
     $storeUrl []=$temp;
   }
 }
```

I need the result like this:

1. `href=/public/coursecontent/2017-08-03-12-bhnhlwdjzyblelskiard.docx`
2. `href=/public/coursecontent/2016-07-07-07-rncsuatxhkkbeomysbmk.docx`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match and preg\_match\_all functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088836/php-preg-match-and-preg-match-all-functions)

Comment: @showdev, Thanks for your reply, i tried preg_match_all() but it is not returnig all href tags.

Comment: @Madhu Can you show examples of href attributes it is not returning?

Comment: <p><a href="https://myedkey.org/#/content/14066">Chapter 1</a></p>

<p><a href="https://myedkey.org/#/content/14066">Chapter 2</a></p>,  There were two href tags is there, i need the result like i mentioned while posting the queston in the above numbers 1 and 2.

Comment: If you are using regex, be sure to include a delimiter; [here's an example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/s7ju-71fb) using `preg_match_all`. However, you may want to consider [zbee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57227328/924299), particularly the suggestion about using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @showdev.

Comment: @MadhuMsd If you question has been answered, accepting an answer with the check mark can help others find an answer in the future and aid the rest of the community in focusing efforts.

Answer (score 3):

My first point would be that [regular expressions may well not be the path you want to take in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/1843510).

But continuing with it, you might try [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of `preg_match` to find multiple occurrences and store them in an array, and from there in your `foreach` you can run a `preg_match_all` and store it in an array and [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) this into your `$storeUrul` array.

---

However, I believe a simpler approach to this, that is most likely more reliable as well would be to parse the HTML and work from the DOM. [Here is a brief guide](https://www.codexworld.com/extract-all-urls-from-web-page-using-php/), that simplifies to something like this in your case:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("a");

for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++){
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $storeUrl[] = $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the title is js regex...

```
 const myString = '...'
 const regex = /href=".+?"/gi;
 const regex2 = /(?<=href=").+?(?=")/gi;
 //regex2 is without 'href' and "
 myString.match(regex);
```

Comment: In a quick test, this did not work. Particularly in the case of there being more than one link, or there being any additional quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply@ Alerks Sir , but it is not working for me.

Comment: Alerks sir, this time it is returning only one href.

Comment: Can you give me a test string? I was matching '<p><a href="myedkey.org/#/content/14066">Chapter 1</a></p> <p><a href="myedkey.org/#/content/14066">Chapter 2</a></p>' with 2 results.

Comment: <a href="https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/two-var-linear-equations/slope-intercept-form/a/introduction-to-slope-intercept-form">
<a href="https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/two-var-linear-equations/graphing-slope-intercept-equations/a/graphing-slope-intercept-form">
<a href="https://www.khanacademy.org/exercise/graph-from-slope-intercept-equation" >

Comment: @Alerks sir in the 'string' huge text is there, comment section  is not allowing to me to post hole data.

Comment: Add it to codePen and share it with me this way. https://codepen.io/ You can link here the pen you've created. https://www.regextester.com/27540

Comment: https://codepen.io/Madhu9652/pen/YmpGPm, @Aleks sir in the html editor i pasted the text, this is only one column, like this there are many columns is there, and those hole column data i stored into the '$result[]' array.

Comment: same regex should work in php, i think, so...preg_match("(?<=href=").+?(?=")",$temp) for you

Comment: https://codepen.io/Madhu9652/pen/VomKrY?editors=1111 @Aleks, please look at this, initial one it seems working fine but when i try to test other strings it is not working fine.

Comment: you need to add 'body' tag around html

Comment: https://codepen.io/alekslario/pen/XvNjZo?editors=1111 same but with body tag OR do document.documentElement.outerHTML. That will grab extra links around codepen frame though

Comment: Aleks sir,  we are getting this data(String text) from the database using the sql query, How can we add the 'body' tag to this data?

Comment: codepen is just and example. With js you  call .match(regex); on a variable( string aka your column) const result = column.match(regex); With php, regex should be the same so... try this preg_match_all("/(?<=href=").+?(?=")/i",$temp)

Comment: I'm not php expert tho

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Aleks sir, finally i got it.